# Unit test say that cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to run a unity test on a method by mocking an addressList but it says that it cannot read the property of undefined.

The method:

```
  async paginate(
    user: User,
    options: IPaginationOptions,
  ): Promise<Pagination<AddressResponse>> {
    const pagination = await this.addressRepository.paginate(user, options);

    return new Pagination(
      await Promise.all(
        pagination.items.map(async (address) => new AddressResponse(address)),
      ),
      pagination.meta,
      pagination.links,
    );
  }
```

The problem is, when I put a console.log() to read the variable "pagination" it shows me an array that is not empty on the concole:

```
console.log
    addressList:  [ Address {} ]
```

this is what the repository is returning to me.

The test that I'm trying to run is this one:

```
  describe('AddressService', () => {
  let addressService: AddressService;
  const user = new User();
  const addressList: Address[] = [new Address()];

  console.log('addressList: ', addressList);

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AddressService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(AddressRepository),
          useValue: {
            paginate: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(addressList),
            create: jest.fn(),
            save: jest.fn(),
            findById: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn(),
            update: jest.fn(),
            delete: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    addressService = module.get<AddressService>(AddressService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(addressService).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('paginate', () => {
    it('should return an address list successfully', async () => {
      // Act
      const result = await addressService.paginate(user, {
        page: 1,
        limit: 10,
      });

      // Assert
      expect(result).toEqual(addressList);
    });
  });
});
```

What is the issue with my code? I'm trying to fix this by days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `paginate` variable is indeed defined and populated, but the property you first accecss in the code is not. You try to access `paginate.items` while your mock just returns an array of `Address`. Change your `paginate` mock to be `paginate: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ items: addressList })` and it should be fixed

Comment: Thanks, lad! You just saved my life! I didn't know what else to do!